# Copy/PasteSpecial Offset macro is slow when switching between worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, offset

**Intro:** I've been working on this macro for quite awhile and have had success getting it to do what I need it to do, however I'm not doing it the most efficient way as my coding background is minimal. Because of this the macro is extremely slow due to switching back and forth from one worksheet "FB MATE DATA" to another "Sheet 2 (2)" copying and pasting data.

**Background:** A CMM machine spits out measurement data into a spreadsheet that I need to copy and paste from one sheet to another in neat X and Y columns to be overlayed in a scatter plot. The problem is that the data is in an unconventional pattern that requires the use of an offset, and different sheets have data that starts in different rows so the macro must account for that. The reason it is so slow is because the way i have achieved this is by constantly activating each worksheet back and forth, over and over to maintain control over the active cell instead of just referencing an offset from a fixed cell due to the offset changing occasionally in a row. The code i have now:

- cycles down through column A until it finds a blank cell
- shifts down to the cell immediately below it and starts copying data over. (This is very important because the first few rows are data irrelevant to me, and they are separated from the data i seek by a space.)
- copies data from the range (G:FZ) in an offset (e.g. G21, K21, O21, S21, W21, AA21, AE21, AI21, AM21, AQ21, AU21, AY21, BG21) into a neat X|Y table from D73:E:93. Notice the irregular pattern (due to info extraneous to my plot)
- Every two represent an X|Y pair (e.g. X: G21 pasted into D73 in Sheet 2, Y: K21 pasted into E73 in Sheet 2, etc.)

**Problem:** For each row of data, I need to copy certain columns in an interval that changes (first column, fourth column, ninth column, twelvth column, etc.) and paste it into two X|Y columns on another page.

The data grab *will not* always start in G21. Sometimes the first data point may be G24, or G10, or G15, hence why the macro searches for a blank row first instead of pulling from a fixed position. Below is a sample of cycling through the first four columns.

**Code:**

```
 Sub LocatorTest()

'Select first row of eligible spare pallet data
 Range("B73").Select
 Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FB MATE DATA").Range("A1"))
 Dim c
 For Each c In Range("A1:A100").Cells
    If c = "" Then
        c.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 6).Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Range("C73").Select
Worksheets("FB MATE DATA").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=4).Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Range("B74").Select
Worksheets("FB MATE DATA").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=8).Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("C74").Select
Worksheets("FB MATE DATA").Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=12).Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2 (2)").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Any help you can provide into maybe a different way of achieving this or making it run quicker would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

o wow, this can use some MAJOR improvements.

but to make it easy, you might want to put this at the start:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

and this at the end of your macro:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This will give it huge speed boost already. Next; you should try to reference to the cells without activating...

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Disabling the screen updating did help a bunch. Now I guess the main question is how to reference that specific cell without using a fixed cell, and then reference the rest of the data points off that original cell without calling it out directly.

Comment: don't forget the upvote if you liked the answer :). With regards to the rest, i strongly recommend you to do a vba excel tutorial. In the meanwhile, access your cells like this for example: worksheets("sheetname").Cells(y,x)  (instead of using "range"). then you also don't need to use "select". These things help already a lot in optimizing...

Comment: I don't have enough rep points yet. I upvoted and it said I need 15 for my upvotes to publicly display. Thanks a bunch for your help, regarding the cell accessing, could I name the first cell a variable and reference the variable within (y,x)? Because its hard to reference something that isn't in a fixed location.